# Win8 apps with certificate expired

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, lob

one year ago we have deployed a windows 8 app signed by a test certificate to our customer,who installed this app after importing the .cer certificate on every involved tablet.
Now this .cer certificate will expire in a few days.
On test device we moved the date of tablet than a year in the future and the app continue to run, we have removed the certificate also from the certificate manager mmc and tha app continue to work.

We receive an error when we try to update or reinstall the app,and this,I know that is correct.

So, my question is:

a windos 8 app can continue to work correctly with expired certificate,there someone who can confirm this ?

Thanks

Marco

Comment: This is a duplicate of [What happens when the package signing certificate expires](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258706/what-happens-when-the-package-signing-certificate-expires). The app should continue to work. Another example you can do is create a custom certificate that expires soon (a few hours or a day after creation). Create a test app, sign it with the cert, install it, then wait.

Comment: Hi Nate,thanks for your response.I followed your advice and the app seem to work correctly with the certificate expired.